# trying to solve this issue for an assignment

Tags: python

i am trying to figure this out it is a homework assignment hopefully someone can help, basically it is a 3d array in python it will run through 1 iteration but then it gives me the error 'int' object has no attribute 'append'here is a copy of the code:

```
dailyFuel = []
totalCostOfFuel = 0
numberOfPeople = int(input('How many passengers for this trip?\n'))
numberOfDays = int(input('How many days will this trip last?\n'))
totalFoodCost = 0
numberOfMeals =1   
dailyFood = [[[]]]
for tripDayindex in range(numberOfDays):
    dailyFood.append(int(input('enter day')))
    for peopleindex in range(numberOfPeople):
        name=int(input('Please enter passenger number\n'))        
        dailyFood[tripDayindex].append(name)
        print(dailyFood)
        for costOfFoodIndex in range(numberOfMeals):
            dailyFood[tripDayindex][peopleindex].append(int(input('How much did you spend on food today?\n')))
print(dailyFood)
```

Comment: Try stepping through your code using a debugger. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I think that the way you create dailyFood means that you are hoping it will be a 3D array.